# jQuery Not Firing on() change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax call that returns a JSON object with a select drop down list like so:

```
{
    "responseCode": 200,
    "field_value": "1",
    "field_options": {
        "175": "Incorrect Listing",
        "176": "High Return Rate",
        "177": "Easily Damaged"
    },
    "selectOptions": "<select id=\"do_not_order_options_102450\" class=\"input-medium\"><option value=\"\">Choose Option<\/option><option value=\"175\">Incorrect Listing<\/option><option value=\"176\">High Return Rate<\/option><option value=\"177\">Easily Damaged<\/option><\/select>"
}
```

On my page I am outputting the select drop down list. (I have a lot of these on my page btw.)

In my jQuery script I have this set up:

```
 $(function(){
        $('select[id^="do_not_order_options_"]').on("change",function(){
            alert(1);
        });
 });
```

It is not firing when I choose an option... Anyone know what may be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: @JFit: It's hidden in the JSON. Scroll right. Presumably the string frm the JSON is being appended to the page.

Comment: ah, thats why.. check TJ's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've quoted will hook up the event handler for the matching select boxes that exist **right then**. But if you add more to the page, their `change` event is not hooked.

You may want to look at event delegation:

```
$(function() {
    $('some container all these selects share').on('change', 'select[id^="do_not_order_options"]', function() {
        // Handle change
    });
});
```

jQuery [ensures that the `change` event bubbles](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), and so we can hook it on a container element and use jQuery's assistance to trigger our handler only for matching elements (selects, in this case).

Since we hook the event on the container, adding more selects inside the container makes them magically work.

Comment: @f00bar: Oh, he/she knows this stuff. I think it was the typing speed that impressed. (Some of the best advice my mother ever gave me in High School was: "You're into computers; take typing.")

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, I missed the anchor part `:p` [Delegation section](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data)